# Recommended hardware for opencv multiple cameras

Tags: c++, opencv

I apologize if I simply am failing with google-fu but I am unable to find the answer to my problem.

I have been working on a project that uses two cameras (and eventually four) to take and analyze data using open cv. The project is updating each frame and does things like movement tracking and object recognition. However, I am using my custom built desktop with a hex core i7-5820k and GTX 980 ti... I can't determine what hardware I need to build a dedicated machine for this project. If someone could reccomend a processor or number of logistical cores needed for something like this, that would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Check what can be processed on your GPU first...